# Learning basics of Flash related to video streaming?

Tags: flash

I am currently working on a on-demand video project. There's a lot of aspects to this such as the recording, transcoding, setting up a streaming server etc. The client will be a Flash powered webclient. However there is one problem with that: I don't know any Flash (I'm a C++ developer).

I am willing to spend some days or weeks learning Flash. However, the size of the Flash universe is somewhat overwhelming. I would greatly appreciate it if somebody would summarize which topics I need to learn in order to use Flash for video playback.

The features that should be implemented for the video player are:

- playback of the video
- table of contents that can be clicked to jump to the corresponding video segment

So that's not too much I think.

And one final but very important question: *do I need a paid license in order to create Flash applications?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GotoAndLearn](http://www.gotoandlearn.com) is a /great/ resource. Make sure you select to view ActionScript 3 tutorials, rather than ActionScript 2.

Also, take a look at the [ActionScript 3 API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/index.html). There are some examples at the bottom of each page. Classes you want to become familiar with:

- flash.net.NetStream
- flash.net.NetConnection
- flash.media.Video
- flash.media.Sound
- flash.media.SoundChannel
- flash.media.SoundTransform

Comment: @Jeremy White: I currently looking into FlashBuilder: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder4/tutorials/gettingstarted/ Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Flash Builder might be a good way to go, but if you don't also have Flash IDE, you'll need to look into learning Flex for building your UI. I do some pretty heavy AS development, and I like to stick with Flash IDE because you get the WYSIWYG editor. There is some workflow integration between the two, but that integration still needs improvement at the moment. My suggestion: watch some workflow tutorials and see what suits you best: Flash IDE only, Flash Builder only, or some combo of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You do need a paid license, flash is proprietary. You might be able to get away with working in a demo. If you can get the project done in 30 days.

Remember all of your videos need to have a constant bitrate.

you are also going to need to load your table of contents dynamically. For that I suggest json, but you could also use xml.

[JSON loading tutorial](http://www.cakesgood.com/2009/04/flash-cs3-actionscript-30-json-keep-it_3277.html)

Comment: Flash video can be encoded with a VBR in FLV or F4V/MP4 format with the Adobe Media Encoder that comes with Flash CS4.

Comment: Also, you technically do need a license if you are using Flash Professional or Flash Builder, but the Flex framework is free and there are a number of free, open source ActionScript compilers out there. (see http://osflash.org/open_source_flash_projects)

Comment: good things to know. especially for those of us that don't have CS4.